# why exclusive lock of insert statement doesn't work

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions

Suppose there are two transactions executed in sequence:

Transaction 1:

```
    BEGIN TRANSACTION 
         INSERT INTO my_table values(1, 'First')
    --not committed
```

Transaction 2:

```
    BEGIN TRANSACTION 
          INSERT INTO my_table values(1, 'First')
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Why Transaction 2 allow to obtain the exclusive lock to complete query, instead of suspending?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the exclusive lock in the example in your question will likely be taken on a row.

With only `IX` locks taken on higher objects in the hierarchy such as page and object.

This does not block a transaction inserting a different row as `IX` locks are [not mutually exclusive](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186396(v=sql.105).aspx).

With the following table example

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
  (
     X INT,
     Y VARCHAR(100)
  )
```

and using `DBCC TRACEON(1200, -1, 3604)` to see the locking info it returns

> Process 57 acquiring IX lock on OBJECT: 7:48719226:0  (class
>   bit2000000 ref1) result: OK
>
> Process 57 acquiring IX lock on PAGE: 7:1:296  (class bit2000000 ref0)
>   result: OK
>
> Process 57 acquiring X lock on RID: 7:1:296:5 (class bit2000000 ref0)
>   result: OK

If you were to create a table such as the following with row locks disabled (not recommended) you may well encounter blocking as the `X` lock is taken at page level instead.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
  (
     X INT,
     Y VARCHAR(100)
  ) 

  CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX on my_table(X) with(ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = OFF)
```

Comment: Is there a situation you would ever design a table with ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = OFF?

Comment: @Frisbee - I can't think of one. At least I've never felt the need to do so so far. [Taking page locks instead of row locks can sometimes cause big performance improvements](http://sqlperformance.com/2015/07/sql-plan/locking-and-performance) but this is achievable by adding a query hint to the specific queries without reducing concurrency on other queries.

Answer (score 0):

Here if no of records being inserted are small then lock will be taken on row. But this number is huge then SQL server might  escalate row level lock to table level lock.